# In Django, how can I access a parameter in a template?

Tags: django

From my view I'm doing the following:

```
return render(request, 'yabe/login.html', {'error': True})
```

In my template I'm trying

```
{% if error %}
    <div class="error">Authentication error. Please try again</div> 
{% endif %}
```

But it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `django.shortcuts.render` that should work. The problem you might have could be some ContextManager overriding that context variable. Try this:

Your view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def your_view(request):
    ...
    return render(request, 'yabe/login.html', {'errorUsedJustHere': True})
```

Your template:

```
{% if errorUsedJustHere %}
    <div class="error">Authentication error. Please try again</div> 
{% endif %}
```

Extra. You could use [Django Debug Toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) to see what variables are set in the context.